# How do I wrap my text alignment to be dynamically aligned?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hey guys, so I have a problem. For now I'm using my item inside angular `span - float: right`

but the text is so long sometimes it renders like this. is there any way I can align it nicely?

This is what i want to achieve in Proposer Name field.

[image]

Just need some weird css tricks thats all. thanks guys

Comment: Add your code we aren't not magical

Comment: yes sir no problem

Comment: Make a runnable snippet

Answer (score -2):

Fixed. Sorry. Thanks.

I have found the solution of using bootstrap col attribute and text-align: right

Comment: Ok so just delete it

Comment: You may add the full answer with codes to be helpful for others. This is not an answer.